# How to avoid ROLLBACK statement in Raw SQL in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, notify

I am trying to send NOTIFY in postgresql through sqlalchemy. Here is the part of code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.engine.execute("NOTIFY DHCP")
```

Which generates the following SQL code:

```
2016-11-29 14:58:41 +05 [20571-16] postgres@server LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2016-11-29 14:58:41 +05 [20571-17] postgres@server LOG:  statement: NOTIFY DHCP
2016-11-29 14:58:41 +05 [20571-18] postgres@server LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
```

Why do i have ROLLBACK statement in the code and how to change to COMMIT one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the best solution that i could find:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
connection = db.engine.connect()
transaction = connection.begin()
try:
    connection.execute("NOTIFY DHCP")
    transaction.commit()
except:
    transaction.rollback()
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do:

```
db.session.execute("...")
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: A bit more info is needed here, which can be found at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#getting-a-session